# In angular2 Injected an service in ngModule provider and trying to use in components not working

Tags: angular

In angular2 rc5 version, Injected an service in ngModule provider (root level) and trying to use that in components but am getting issue like can not find "servicename".
Here is my code,

Root file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherService } from './other.service';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [ AppComponent ],
 imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormsModule ],
 providers: [OtherService],
 entryComponents: [AppComponent],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
    getUsername(){
        return 'from other service';
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styles: [':host(.selected) {display:block;background:#ccc;}']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!!';

      constructor(private otherSer: OtherService){};
    }
```

Am getting issue, as "can not find name 'OtherService' in component 'app.component'".

Please correct me if am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import `OtherService` in your `app.component` as well because you are adding it to your constructor and its name cannot be resolved without import.